# Gremlin: Find duplicates of a vertex by 'name' property and execute as list of 'id'

Tags: orientdb, gremlin

The below code groups all userProfileTemplates by name, finds where there are duplicates and then projects the "name" of the userProfileTemplate where the count of name is > 1. I want to find duplicates by "name", but I want to execute it as a list of "Id" (Id is a property of userProfileTemplate). Any suggestions?

`g.V().hasLabel('userProfileTemplate').group().by(values('name').fold()).unfold().filter(select(values).count(local).is(gt(1))).select(keys)unfold().project('Duplicate User Profiles')`

Update: The below is executing a column named "value" with the multiple 'id' that correspond to the duplicate 'name', separated by commas in betweeen brackts.

`g.V().hasLabel('userProfileTemplate').group().by('name').by('id').unfold().filter(select(values).count(local).is(gt(1))).select(values)`

I would like to also execute a column that shows the corresponding 'name' for all duplicate ids.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's almost what you already have, you only need to add another `by()`.

```
g.V().hasLabel('userProfileTemplate').
  group().
    by('name').
    by('Id').
  unfold().
  filter(select(values).count(local).is(gt(1))).
  select(keys)
```

Comment: This worked, except I changed the last select(keys) to select(values) to return the Ids rather than the names. This query is much faster than the one I put in the question as well, so thanks!!

Comment: Update: I did select(values) as shown on the original question, but I want to also execute a column with the actuall user that is duplicated. So currently, the query is executing a list of values, separated by commas between brackets, and I want the corresponding duplicate 'name' as another column. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, if you just remove the `select(values)` from the end, you get what you need, no?

Comment: That's not helpful. What kind of error? The query is valid, otherwise, the full query wouldn't work either.

Comment: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Cannot convert yukgupta=[1893159, 1586097] - class java.util.HashMap$Node to JSON

Comment: So, that just looks like a serialization problem. To get around it, you can project the result into a different structure. E.g. `project('name','ids').by(keys).by(values)`.